# single quote gets converted to 2 single quotes while importing csv via sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am importing a csv file via sql developer. I am having a column that can have multiple comma and single quote values. Hence in order to escape it I am enclosing the column data in double quotes like `"column_value"` in csv file. However on import the single quote in data are replaced by 2 single quotes .

For example if data is like `test,a'b'c` then data in column becomes `test,a''b''c` after csv import. what could be issue here?

**Update :**  I found one workaround , in the final stage of sql developer import there is a checkbox `"send to SQL worksheet"`. On selecting this option and on clicking on import insert scripts got generated. On running these insert scripts separately data got inserted properly

Comment: Do you mean `INSERT INTO` script or value in grid after `SELECT * FROM target_table`?

Comment: There is no issue - if you will insert the values in a table, the single quotes MUST be escaped as you have shown. When they are inserted, each doubled single-quote becomes a single single-quote.

Comment: @lad2025: I meant select sql shows double quotes

Comment: Show an example of input data and output data please

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO The description of issue has example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one workaround , in the final stage of sql developer import there is a checkbox `send to SQL worksheet`. On selecting this option and on clicking on import insert scripts got generated. On running these insert scripts separately data got inserted properly